# rel="next" isn't added to head in custom query and page post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, ref

i want a numberic pagination in my custom query. therefor i use this script in my function:

```
function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {

if( is_singular() )
    return;

global $wp_query;

/** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

/** Add current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 1 )
    $links[] = $paged;

/** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
    $links[] = $paged - 2;
}

if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 2;
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
}

echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

/** Previous Post Link */
if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) {
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link(__('Previous Page','tkh').'') );
    add_filter( 'wpseo_prev_rel_link', get_previous_posts_link() );
}

/** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>';
}

/** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
sort( $links );
foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
}

/** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

    $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
}

/** Next Post Link */
if ( get_next_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link(__('Next Page','tkh').'') );

echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
}
```

to add the rel="next" and rel="prev" meta tags i use:

```
function cor_rel_next_prev_pagination() {

global $wp_query;
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
//print_r( wp_count_pages() );

if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) { ?>
<link rel="prev" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 ); ?>">
<?php
}
if ( get_next_posts_link('',5) ) { ?>
<link rel="next" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged + 1 ); ?>">
<?php
}
}
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head');
add_action('wp_head', 'cor_rel_next_prev_pagination');
```

And now my problem: You see in the second script get_next_posts_link('',5). When i write a static numberic (5) into the function it is workly perfectly. But i can't make it work dynamically (e.g. with: $wp_query->max_num_pages). Probably because $wp_query isn't init in the wp_head action. Also i can't use wp_count_posts() because i think it is not working with a post_type page. So mainly: How can't get the  working. Andy suggestions?

By the way, here is how i setup the query in my page:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $news_events = array(
                'numberposts'       => -1,
                'post_type'         => ['news','event'],
                'orderby'           => 'date',
                //'posts_per_page'  => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
                'posts_per_page'    => 1,
                'paged'             => $paged
            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($news_events);

            if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
```

Comment: If you have a solution, you can add it as an answer rather than an edit to the question. You don't need to *accept* it as the best answer though--maybe wait until someone comes up with an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

For now i found a solution. but its not perfect. I added in the cor_rel_next_prev_pagination() function this line:

```
if ( get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() ) == news_events) $max = ceil( (wp_count_posts('event')->publish + wp_count_posts('news')->publish ) / get_option('posts_per_page') ); else $max = wp_count_posts()->publish / get_option('posts_per_page');
```

and also in the same function:

```
if ( get_next_posts_link('', $max ) ) { ?>
```

but maybe someone got a better solution.